# Set Magento Product Group Permissions Programatically

Tags: php, magento

When you edit a Product in Magento there is a Permissions tab with two multi-selects on it.

> Disable product for

and

> Hide product price for

We need to set the Disable product groups programatically by including 'Mage.php' and using a script to update the Disabled Groups.

For example we want to Disable a product for 10 specific groups for a product. We've been able to do pretty much everything else you can do in the Admin Interface in script so there should be a way to access this using Mage::getModel('catalog/product') or another Model. Call a function, pass in the group ID's you want to set the product to disabled for.

But can't seem to track it down.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found where the data is stored in the database and just ended up modifying the database directly.

$groupsDisabledArray is an array that contains an ID for each group I want to disable product permissions for. The data in magento is simply stored as a comma separated list of Group ID's

Example:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

So I implode my disabled group ID's array to get a comma separated list

```
$groupsList=implode(",", $groupsDisabledArray);
```

Then either insert or update the catalog_product_entity_text table which is where the value is stored.

The value is stored in catalog_product_entity_text where

```
entity_id = PRODUCT_ID
attribute_id = 155 (This corresponds to the table eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'aw_cp_disable_product')
entity_type_id = 4 (This corresponds to table eav_entity_type where entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')
store_id = STORE_ID (If you just have one store you should just be able to put 0 here for the Default Store)
```

Code to do the complete update below. May need to update the path to Mage.php depending where you put your script.

```
include("/app/Mage.php");

/* Get DB Connections */
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_text');

/* $groupsDisabledArray - Array of all of the Magento Group ID's I want to disable this product for */

$groupsList=implode(",", $groupsDisabledArray);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE entity_id=$product_id AND attribute_id=155 and entity_type_id=4 AND store_id=0;";
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($sql);
if (count($results) > 0) {
    $sql="UPDATE $tableName SET value='$groupsList' WHERE entity_id=$product_id AND attribute_id=155 and entity_type_id=4 AND store_id=0;";
}
else
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO $tableName (entity_id, entity_type_id, store_id, attribute_id, value) VALUES ($product_id, 4, 0, 155, '$groupsList')";
}
$writeConnection->query($sql);
```